# GSON не сериализует поле типа LocalDate

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gson, localdate

При попытке сеарилизовать поле типа LocalDate - теряется его значение. В чём проблема?

```
    package com.example.myapplication;
    
    import android.content.SharedPreferences;
    import android.os.Build;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    
    import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
    import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;
    
    import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
    
    import android.view.View;
    import com.google.gson.Gson;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    
    import java.time.LocalDate;
    
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    
            FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
            fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .setAction("Action", null).show();
                }
            });
        }
    
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
            return true;
        }
    
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            int id = item.getItemId();
            //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
            if (id == R.id.action_settings)
            {
                LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now();
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("SharedPreferences123", MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                String json = gson.toJson(gson.toJson(localDate));
                editor.putString("MyCounting", json);
                editor.apply();
                return true;
            }
    
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Как вы определили что значение теряется? Выведите хотя бы в лог полученную строку: `Log.d("TAG", "JSON: " + json);` Подозреваю что проблема вовсе не в сериализации.

Comment: Точка останова)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте сохранить дату в численом представлении

```
val time = localDate.toEpochDay()
```

Запишите long

```
editor.putLong("MyTime", time);
```

Воссоздать дату очень легко

```
val date = LocalDate.ofEpochDay(time)
```

Для сериализации LocalDate нужна конвертация

Answer (score 1):

```
Переработал функции следующим образом:
if(id == R.id.action_SaveCountingEntries)
        {
            if(!countingEntries.isEmpty())
            {
                ArrayList<SaveDataObject> saveDataObjects = new ArrayList<SaveDataObject>();
                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("SharedPreferencesForArrayList<CountingEntries>", MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                for(int i = 0; i < countingEntries.size(); i++)
                {
                    saveDataObjects.add(new SaveDataObject(countingEntries.get(i).GetPurchase(),countingEntries.get(i).GetCost(),countingEntries.get(i).GetDateOfPurchase().toEpochDay()));
                }
                String json = gson.toJson(saveDataObjects);
                editor.putString("MyCountingEntries", json);
                editor.apply();
                Toast.makeText(this, "Облікові записи успішно збережено!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Відсутні облікові записи для збереження!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        if(id == R.id.action_LoadCountingEntries)
        {
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("SharedPreferencesForArrayList<CountingEntries>", MODE_PRIVATE);
            String json = sharedPreferences.getString("MyCountingEntries",null);
            if(!json.isEmpty())
            {
                ArrayList<SaveDataObject> saveDataObjects = new ArrayList<SaveDataObject>();
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<SaveDataObject>>() {}.getType();
                saveDataObjects = gson.fromJson(json, type);
                countingEntries.clear();
                for(int i = 0; i < saveDataObjects.size(); i++)
                {   
                    long longdate = saveDataObjects.get(i).dateOfpurchase;
                    countingEntries.add(new CountingEntry(saveDataObjects.get(i).purchase,saveDataObjects.get(i).cost, LocalDate.ofEpochDay(longdate)));
                }
                RefreshList();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Відсутні облікові записи для завантаження!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return true;
        }
И объект для сохранение:
package com.example.personalaccounting;

public class SaveDataObject
{
    public String purchase;
    public int cost;
    public long dateOfpurchase;
    public SaveDataObject(String purchase_, int cost_, long dateOfpurchase_)
    {
        purchase = purchase_;
        cost = cost_;
        dateOfpurchase = dateOfpurchase_;
    }
}
```